# My site won't scroll all of a sudden

Tags: html, css, scroll

Starting today out of the blue, my site won't scroll:
http://www.rowthree.com/

There is a ton of content, but I can't go below a certain point.  I don't have the body or html set to overflow: hidden;

So no idea what's going on.  Thoughts?

Comment: your body element is not closed properly

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start using something like [https://validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#page` has overflow:hidden on it and your body tag is:

```
<body class="home blog group-blog su-other-shortcodes-loaded" <div="" id="page">
```

This isn't a valid body tag, but the browser is reading it as having an id of "page" because of that last part.

Answer (score -1):

did you make any changes? you could always  roll back those changes or diff them to see what has  changed.

you could   add  `overflow: auto`  one of your CSS classes

Comment: This should be a comment since you're not giving an answer but trying to clarify the question